# Polynomial decomposition complexity

Tags: algebraic-complexity, polynomials

Given $N(x)\in\Bbb Z_{\geq0}[x]$ with non-negative coefficients with promise that there exists $a(x),b(x),c(x),d(x)\in\Bbb Z_{\geq0}[x]$ with non-negative coefficients such that $N(x)=a(x)b(x)+c(x)d(x)$ with $\mathsf{deg}(a(x)b(x))=\mathsf{deg}(c(x)d(x))=\mathsf{deg}(N(x))$, $\mathsf{deg}(a(x))=\mathsf{deg}(b(x))=\mathsf{deg}(c(x))=\mathsf{deg}(d(x))=\frac{\mathsf{deg}(N(x))}2$, what is the complexity of decomposing $N(x)$? Assume that each coefficient of constituent polynomials could be represented using $n$ bits.

If there are many quadruples $a(x),b(x),c(x),d(x)$, finding one suffices.

Comment: We need a little more context: what does "decomposing" mean here? Is it finding $a,b,c$? What if there exist several such polynomials?

Comment: Yes finding $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Finding one quadruple in $\Bbb Z_{\geq0}[x]$ suffices.